# How Can make this JSX compact?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

```
{
  this.state.isLoadingInputDropDown &&
  <option value="-1" disabled >Loading...</option >
}

{/* TODO : was not able to combine below statements */}
{
  !this.state.isLoadingInputDropDown
  && <option value="-1" >--Select a Accessorial Charge first --</option>
}
{                                            
  !this.state.isLoadingInputDropDown
  && this.state.allInputs.length > 0
  && this.state.allInputs.map(
    (input) => (<option value={input.id} key={input.id}>{input.name}</option>)
  )
}
```

trying to make this JSX one-liner or something compact.
I tried every possible (which I can think of) structure

Comment: Why would you want to make this more compact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, split the whole function into two parts:

```
let options;

if (this.state.isLoadingInputDropDown) {
   const defaultOption = <option value="-1" disabled >Loading...</option>;
   options = [defaultOption];
} else {
   const defaultOption = <option value="-1" >--Select a Accessorial Charge first --</option>;
   const choices = this.state.allInputs.map(
       (input) => (<option value={input.id} key={input.id}>{input.name}</option>)
   )
   options = [defaultOption, ...choices];
}

return (
   <select>
      {options}
   </select>
);
```

The `this.state.allInputs.length > 0` check is not necessary.

Don't try to make this a one-liner. It's not important how long code is. The important thing is to make it readable. You should actually consider splitting this piece of code into multiple functions.

Comment: In general you are right. But if you do so avoid mutating variables and use statements instead of expressions which cause no side effects.

Comment: @Tobias I did not get what you said.

Comment: I just meant: Try to avoid "let" (let options = ...) statements and use "const". This will automatically cause a refactoring of your code sample which will replace the mutation of "options" with an assignment of options which is the better way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you declare the content before returning jsx.

```
const dropdown = this.state.isLoadingInputDropDown ? <option value="-1" disabled >Loading...</option > : <option value="-1" >--Select a Accessorial Charge first --</option>;

const otherOptions = this.state.isLoadingInputDropDown || !(this.state.allInputs.length > 0) ? null : this.state.allInputs.map(
    (input) => (<option value={input.id} key={input.id}>{input.name}</option>)
);

return (
    <select>
        { dropdown }
        { otherOptions }
    </select>
);
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning, was on a hurry :-D

Comment: Hate to say it, but it will still fail, if he do not have a extra component named `Select` .. :)

Comment: damn... anything else left? :-D

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this;

```
return (
    <select>
        {this.state.isLoadingInputDropDown
            ? <option value="-1" disabled >Loading...</option>
            : [{ id: -1, name: '--Select a Accessorial Charge first --'}, ...this.state.allInputs].map(
                (input) => (<option value={input.id} key={input.id}>{input.name}</option>)
            )}
    </select>
)
```